# Can Doctrine's resolve_target_entities be used for discovering repositories?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 2.8.3 with Doctrine 2.4.8 on two projects (**ProjectA** and **ProjectB**) and wanted to create a shared service in my bundle (**SharedBundle**).

This service needs to operate on the database so I thought I could use the resolve_target_entities directive in config.yml to gain access to my project's repository (defined in ProjectA and ProjectB) from SharedBundle.

The repository looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace My\ProjectA\Repository;

class FooRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    // ...
}
```

### First attempt - interface

app/config:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        # ...
        resolve_target_entities:
            My\SharedBundle\Model\FooInterface: My\ProjectA\Entity\Foo
```

So I've created an interface:

```
<?php

namespace My\SharedBundle\Model;

interface FooInterface 
{
}
```

The entity implements this interface

```
<?php

namespace My\ProjectA\Entity;

class Foo implements \My\SharedBundle\Model\FooInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Trying to access the repository from SharedService like this:

```
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(\My\SharedBundle\Model\FooInterface::class);
```

This throws:

`Class 'My\SharedBundle\Model\FooInterface' does not exist`

### Second attempt - abstract entity

app/config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        # ...
        resolve_target_entities:
            My\SharedBundle\Model\AbstractFoo: My\ProjectA\Entity\Foo
```

I create an abstract entity

```
<?php

namespace My\SharedBundle\Model;

abstract class AbstractFoo
{
    // ...
}
```

Inheritance:

```
<?php

namespace My\ProjectA\Entity;

class Foo extends AbtractFoo
{
    // ...
}
```

Now I wanted to access the repository from SharedService like this:

```
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(\My\SharedBundle\Model\AbstractFoo::class);
```

But this throws:

`The class 'My\SharedBundle\Model\AbstractFoo' was not found in the chain configured namespaces My\ProjectA\Entity`

Is this applicable to doctrine relations only?

Answer (score 1):

DoctrineBundle's `resolve_target_entities` only works for relations.

You don't need to use this to map different classes (i.e. in two applications) to the same database table actually.

You should just use [inheritance mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) instead.

Create a mapped superclass `class A` (present in both applications) that is extended by `class B` (only present in application #1) and `class C` (only present in application #2).

Comment: This seems similar to my second approach but I didn't define any inheritance in the doctrine yml. I'll try that and let You know ASAP.